# Multilingual wordpress... which plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translation, multilingual

I am making a small blog for someone and they want it in 2 languages. I understand there are plugins for multilingual support, however i have not enough time to test many of them and see which is more suitable. For this reason, i will tell you what i want to do and hope you can give me a few recommendations.

This blog will have some articles in one language, some in another, and some in both. When someone clicks the switch language button, i don't need it necessarily to point to the same post, just switch to a homepage view with only articles in that language. I was having a look at qTranslate, can i do this with it? Do you have something else to recommend me for this type of structure?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Wordpress, not progrmamming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**qTranslate** is the best I know so far, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/.

An article can be written in 1 ore more languages up to your choice. This plugin is also easy to personalise, setup, use in code and administrate via blog dashboard.

Good luck! :)

Comment: IMHO qTranslate is far from *the best*. It's quick and easy, I will give you that. What happens when you have to translate content other than the main content and title? (custom fields and various incompatible plugins) You can't.

Answer (score 1):

[WPML](http://wpml.org/) has more than 100 thousand customers and premium support, it also handles different specific scenarios such as menu translation, admin options/custom field translation and more.

It works in a different manner than qTranslate - it creates a single post entry for every translated language which makes it easier to add different values (even categories, tags and fields to every translation) while qTranslate is adding some meta tags to the real post and makes it pretty odd technically wise.